# All kinds of problems with booting

Tags: boot

So, In the past few days, I've been trying to install both Ubuntu and Ubuntu server on my old desktop to run mineOS, and I can't boot because an error: "attempt to read or write outside of disk (hd0)". I've tried using `set root=(hd0,2)` and `set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub`
but it still throws the error on ubuntu server. Any answers accepted!

---

Ok, so when I installed ubuntu (I'm not trying to dualboot) it gives the error `error: unknown file system Entering grub rescue grub rescue>`, and I tried the `ls` command with every partition but it said unknown filesystem every time. I tried using boot repair to fix it, but its asking me to boot in EFI mode when I'm already booted in EFI mode. With Ubuntu server, after installation, it says `error: attempt to read or write outside of disk (hd0)`. I tried the `set root=(hd0,examplepartition)` and `set prefix=(hd0,examplepartition)/boot/grub`, but it then said `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found`. Currently the BIOS boot options are AUTO, NON-EFI, and EFI.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking and there aren't many details to work with. Are you having problems *installing* Ubuntu, or are you having trouble *booting* an otherwise working system, or is this question about something else entirely? What version of Ubuntu are you using? If you're having trouble with installing Ubuntu, start over and follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you still need help, reference the tutorial when asking. You should also [verify](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu) your installation media is valid.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The server editions of most Linux distributions are not designed to be used in a multi-boot environment, as servers are servers, not part-time devices. If the desktop version of Ubuntu is missing something that you can find on Ubuntu Server, then perhaps it would be better to install those packages rather than employ a multi-boot environment 

Comment: sounds like the partitioning is all messed up. If you have time then put a new partition table on the computer.  gpt.  And then do the install.

Comment: Please edit your question when you want to provide additional information about the problem. Do not put these in comments or as an answer to the question.

Comment: Is your computer 32 bit?

Comment: 64 bit, as far as I know, but I'm unsure